# Can magit commit with all (-a / --all) instead of "." by default?

Tags: magit

When using `magit-commit-create`, internally it runs something like...

- `git commit .` instead of...
- `git commit -a`

Is there a way to make magit use `-a` / `--all` by default instead?

---

Note: this is an important difference because this causes sub-modules to be committed each time, which I don't want to do *(since the sub-modules have master checked out and I don't want to be changing the submodule `sha1` for every commit)*.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting  `magit-commit-arguments`, for example:

```
(setq magit-commit-arguments '("--all"))
```